# Passing EntityManager object to all BusinessLayer methods

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, entitymanager

I would like to know if passing a reference to an EntityManager object to all my BusinessLayer methods is an anti-pattern or no.

```
public void setCost(EntityManager em, int idProduct);

public void updateProduct(EntityManager em, ProductEntity product);
```

I find this pattern practical since it let me manage the grouping of muliple methods to build personalised transactions...

```
public void initProduct(EntityManager em, ProductEntity product) {
    ...
    tx.begin()
    ...
    setCost(em, idProduct);
    updateProduct(em, product);
    ...
    tx.commit(); 
}
```

PS:

- I am not using the Spring Framework.
- The JPA based Business Layer and Data Access Layer are intended to be
  used in a Desktop App.

Thanks

Comment: The only time I can see this being of any use is if you need different entityManagers from time to time, e.g. working with different datasources.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like an unnecessary effort to pass it as a parameter, since you can inject it much easier through `@PersistenceContext`.

Or if you don't have a dependency injection container, you might want to turn the responsibility other way around anyways. Instead of passing the EntityManager as a parameter, have the implementation fetch it from somewhere (e.g. JNDI).

Comment: Does the @PersistenceContext annotation do the job in a "not web" application (i.e: desktop application)? I am not using the Spring Framework.

Comment: Not really no. You'd need some Dependency Injection framework to handle it for you (CDI, Spring, Guice). But it makes the interface cleaner. What if at some point you decide not to use EntityManager anymore? You'll have to change all the implementations, or pass "null" in there.

Comment: In which case i may decide not to use EntityManager anymore?

Comment: Maybe you decide that you want to write pure JDBC. Maybe you decide that you'll receive the actual data from a web service. Who knows, but that parameter couples the interface to JPA. It might not be a huge issue, but still it's something to consider.